# Get "ALL" value in selectinput to plot with multi-filters (shiny)

Tags: r, filter

I would like to get a reactive plot with multiple filters and an initial minimal plot with the number of ALL diagnostics by month.

The aim requires 4 filters AND a scale of period (display data by week,month ..).

I tried but not it's not working on the step to sum data (ALL).
If you have a suggestion I am open .
Thank you  :)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#data
data.hosp <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                    id= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  Annee = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018),
                  Mois = c("2018-01","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-03"),
                  Semaine = c("2018-001","2018-003","2018-008","2018-011","2018-013"),
                  uf= c("A3352","Z6687", "A3352", "A3352", "Z6687"),
                  um= c(3350,6687, 3352, 3350, 6687),
                  ghm= c("AAAAA","DFFDF","DDFDA","AZEEA","DDFDA"),
                  diag= c("A","A","C","Z","R"),
                  nb=c(1,3,1,1,10))

  ui <- fluidPage(
          titlePanel("Plot with filters"),
        
        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_uf",
                             label = "UF",
                             choices = as.character(unique(data.hosp$uf)), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(200))),
           column(2,
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_um", 
                             label = "UM",
                             choices = as.character(unique(data.hosp$um)), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(200))),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_ghm", 
                             label = "GHM",
                             choices =as.character(unique(data.hosp$ghm)), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(200))),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(inputId = "sel_diag", 
                             label = "Diagnostic",
                             choices =c('Tous', as.character(unique(data.hosp$diag))), 
                             multiple=TRUE,
                             width = validateCssUnit(250))),
          column(4,  selectInput("periodec",
                      label="Affichage par :",
                      choices = c("Semaine"= "Semaine",
                                "Mois"   = "Mois",
                                "Année"  = "Annee"),
                    selected   = "Mois" ) ),
          
          plotOutput("graph1", height=300 )
))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Period filter (display by :)
  periode <- reactive({
    ifelse(input$periodec=="Semaine", "Semaine",
    ifelse(input$periodec=="Mois", "Mois",
    ifelse(input$periodec=="Année", "Annee")))     })
  
 
  # Data filters
  df_dat <- reactive({        
    df_dat  <- data.hosp

  #code to get "ALL" in selectsizeInput 
    if ('Tous' %in% input$sel_diag) { sel_diag <- unique(data.hosp$diag)
    } else {
      data.hosp <- data.hosp %>% filter(nb == input$sel_diag)
      nb <- unique(data.hosp$nb) }

    if (!is.null(input$sel_um)) {
      df_dat  <- df_dat  %>% filter(um == input$sel_um)   %>% group_by_(periode()) %>% summarise(sum_active = sum(nb))}
    if (!is.null(input$sel_uf)) {
      df_dat  <- df_dat  %>% filter(uf == input$sel_uf)   %>% group_by_(periode()) %>% summarise(sum_active = sum(nb))}
    if (!is.null(input$sel_ghm)) {
      df_dat  <- df_dat  %>% filter(ghm == input$sel_ghm)   %>% group_by_(periode()) %>% summarise(sum_active = sum(nb)) }
    if (!is.null(input$sel_diag)) {
      df_dat  <- df_dat  %>% filter(diag == input$sel_diag)   %>% group_by_(periode()) %>% summarise(sum_active = sum(nb)) }
    return(df_dat)
  })
  
  
  # Ensures that our filter works properly
  observe(print(str(df_dat())))
  # graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
    req(df_dat())
    ggplot(df_dat(), aes_string(x =periode(), y = "sum_active",  group = factor(periode() ))) +
             geom_bar(aes_string(periode(), "sum_active"), stat = "identity", fill="steelblue")
  }) 
} 
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. In my opinion the main issue is that your approach was overly complicated. (;

1. My approach sets all filters first. If `NULL` (and/or 'Tous') the "selection" is set to all categories of a variable, otherwise only the chosen ones are included.
2. Doing so you only need one pipe to filter and summarise the data
3. There is no need for the `observe` statement which I dropped
4. I fixed the req in the renderPlot to check wether the filtered data contains any rows. Otherwise ggplot will raise an error.

   ```
   server <- function(input, output) {

     #Period filter (display by :)
     # While a nested ifelse works in the present case a better choice is using `if 
     periode <- reactive({
       if (input$periodec == "Semaine") {
         "Semaine"
       } else if (input$periodec == "Mois") {
         "Mois"  
       } else {
         "Annee"
       }
     })

     df_dat <- reactive({
       # First: Setup the filters. If NULL: all categories else: chosen ctaegories
       # In case of diag additionally check for "Tous"
       sel_diag <- if (is.null(input$sel_diag) | 'Tous' %in% input$sel_diag) unique(data.hosp$diag) else input$sel_diag
       sel_um <- if (is.null(input$sel_um)) unique(data.hosp$um) else input$sel_um
       sel_uf <- if (is.null(input$sel_uf)) unique(data.hosp$uf) else input$sel_uf
       sel_ghm <- if (is.null(input$sel_ghm)) unique(data.hosp$ghm) else input$sel_ghm

       # Filter the data and summarise
       data.hosp %>% 
         filter(diag %in% sel_diag, um %in% sel_um, uf %in% sel_uf, ghm %in% sel_ghm) %>% 
         group_by_(periode()) %>% 
         summarise(sum_active = sum(nb), .groups = "drop")
     })

     # graph 
     output$graph1 <- renderPlot({
       # Plot only if any data
       req(nrow(df_dat()) > 0)
       ggplot(df_dat(), aes_string(x = periode(), y = "sum_active",  group = factor(periode() ))) +
         geom_bar(aes_string(periode(), "sum_active"), stat = "identity", fill="steelblue")
     }) 
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you very much :)